# Break time.sleep() After Collecting Data

Tags: python, multithreading

Here's my code:

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
from msvcrt import getch

key = 0

def ProcessKey(key):
    if key == 97:
        return 1
    elif key == 32:
        return 2
    elif key == 13:
        return 3
    else:
        return 0

def Check():
    sleep(2)
    if key != 0:
        return

Thread(target = Check()).start()
key = ord(getch())
print(ProcessKey(key))
```

The timed input works fine in cutting someone off from entering input but if someone enters input in time I have to wait the full 2 seconds before the next line of code is executed. How can I skip the rest of the 2 seconds after someone enters input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
from msvcrt import getch

key = 0

def ProcessKey(key):
    if key == 97:
        return 1
    elif key == 32:
        return 2
    elif key == 13:
        return 3
    else:
        return 0

def Check():
    sleep(2)
    if key != 0:
        return

Thread(target = Check).start() ##Dont call the function just enter the name I think this will solve
key = ord(getch())
print(ProcessKey(key))
```